# Delete first column of 2d vector matrix read in using sstream

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a 2d vector where the rows are unequal.  I have been trying to delete the first column but have no luck look at previous stackoverflow posts.

example data:

```
1 2 4 5 6 6
1 2 3 4 6 6 8
```

Code to read in data:

```
myfile.open("test.txt");
if(myfile.is_open())
{
    while(getline(myfile, line)){
        //cout << "This line: ";
        if(line != "")
{
            istringstream is(line);
            sortVec.push_back(std::vector<int>( std::istream_iterator<int>(is),
                                                    std::istream_iterator<int>() ) );
        }
  }
}
else
{
    cout << "Myfile is not open" << endl;
}

    myfile.close();
```

When I try to erase the first column using std:vector:

```
int columnIndex = 0;
    for(auto& row:sortVec){
        row.erase(next(row.begin(), columnIndex));
    }
```

I get a segmentation fault.

I have tried the following stackoverflow posts as well.
[How to delete column in 2d vector, c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27264953/how-to-delete-column-in-2d-vector-c)

Additionally when I create a vector manually everything works perfect so I am lost at the moment.

Desired output:

```
2 4 5 6 6
2 3 4 6 6 8
```

The answer was that don't forget to check empty lines when using getline.  The last line of my file was empty.

Comment: Your question has two major flaws, both related. 1. It shows no sings of debugging. This does not mean you haven't debugged, but that any debugging you did was ineffective. This leads to 2. lacking an [mcve]. Give [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) a read and keep an eye out for empty rows.

Comment: @user4581301 thanks for the info.  I'll add more information.

Comment: Why is the code to read in the data relevant?  The code you should be posting is a simple function to delete a column of a 2d vector, and a small `main()` function using hard-coded vectors, calling such function.  How you get the data is not important.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I did try that and it worked but not for when I used the sstream to read in my file

Comment: @user1238097 So this has nothing to do with the deletion of the columns.  It has everything to do with the state of your data before any of this deletion occurs.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie awe dang you are right

Comment: @user1238097 [Cannot duplicate](https://www.ideone.com/J6REMI).  Both vectors, hard-coded and read-in, are identical.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181029/discussion-between-user1238097-and-paulmckenzie).

Comment: [Works for me](http://rextester.com/EGCXZ48056). To the extent there is a problem, it must needs lie in the code you haven't shown.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Yup after checking there is something weird with my input file.

Comment: Thanks all but the error was something in the text file that was causing the error.