# Delete column in 2D std::vector depending on comparison of 2 rows in same column in C++

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, stdvector

I have a 2D `std::vector < std::vector <double> >` array consisting of three rows and an unknown number of columns. I would like to delete any column where the value of `row 0 > row 1`. Here is my effort:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
inline void printArray (const std::vector< std::vector< T > >& key_array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < key_array.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < key_array[i].size(); j++) {
            std::cout << key_array[i][j] << "\t";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    std::vector< std::vector <int> > fog {{1,1,2,1},{2,2,1,2},{3,3,3,3}};
    
    printArray(fog);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < fog[0].size(); ++i) {
                for (int j = 0; j < fog.size(); ++j) {
                    if (fog[0][i] > fog[1][i]) {
                        fog[j].erase(fog[j].begin() + i);
                    }
                }
            }
            
    printArray(fog);
```

The array is initially:

```
1       1       2       1                                                                                                      
2       2       1       2                                                                                                      
3       3       3       3
```

I would like it to become:

```
1       1       1                                                                                                      
2       2       2                                                                                                      
3       3       3
```

Instead I get:

```
1       1       1                                                                                                              
2       2       1       2                                                                                                      
3       3       3       3
```

I imagine the problem is because the size of the array is changing as elements are deleted, invalidating the loop conditions, and/or iterators are being removed. But with this observation, I have reach my (rather circumscribed) limits.

I would be most grateful for any advice.

Comment: I think you mean the condition for deleting is row(i) > row(i+1)?

Comment: @RoQuOTriX, I am *trying* to compare `row 1` to `row 0` in each column, and then removing the column if `row 0` > `row 1`. Whether my code is actually achieving this objective, is another matter! The key part is `if (fog[0][i] > fog[1][i])`, which attempts to compare `row 0` and `row 1` in `column i`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following approach deletes the desired columns "in place" instead of copying. The strategy is adapted from [How to delete column in 2d vector, c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27264953/how-to-delete-column-in-2d-vector-c)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
inline void printArray (const std::vector< std::vector< T > >& key_array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < key_array.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < key_array[i].size(); j++) {
            std::cout << key_array[i][j] << "\t";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    std::vector< std::vector <int> > fog {{2,1,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2},{1,2,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1},{3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3}};
    
    printArray(fog);
    
    
    for (int i = 0; i < fog[0].size(); ++i)
        {
            
            if (fog[0][i] > fog[1][i]) {
                    
                    /* // Alternative
                    std::for_each(fog.begin(), fog.end(), [&](std::vector<int>& row) {
                            row.erase(std::next(row.begin(), i));
                        });
                     */
                    
                   for(auto& row:fog) row.erase(std::next(row.begin(), i));
                
                // accounts for deleted column
                --i;
            }
        }
    
    printArray(fog);
    
}
```

fog before loop is:

```
2   1   1   2   1   2   1   2   1   2   
1   2   2   1   2   1   2   1   2   1   
3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3
```

And fog after loop is:

```
1   1   1   1   1   
2   2   2   2   2   
3   3   3   3   3
```

Perhaps surprisingly, deleting in place did not speed up the operation compared to the copy approach used by me (@Bob) above. Maybe the amount of memory jockeying ends up being similar in both approaches. However, since there is no copying with the deleting in place strategy, it is presumably more efficient in terms of memory footprint.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is "correct" but does not work in-place. One solution would be to copy the array and replace it in the copy while iterating over the old one:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
inline void printArray (const std::vector< std::vector< T > >& key_array) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < key_array.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < key_array[i].size(); j++) {
            std::cout << key_array[i][j] << "\t";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    std::vector< std::vector <int> > fog {{1,1,2,1},{2,2,1,2},{3,3,3,3}};
    
    printArray(fog);
    
    auto fog2 = fog;

    for (int i = 0; i < fog[0].size(); ++i) 
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < fog.size(); ++j) 
        {
            if (fog[0][i] > fog[1][i]) 
            {
                fog2[j].erase(fog2[j].begin() + i);
            }
        }
    }
    
    printArray(fog2);      
}
```

If want to do it in-place you need to change the for-loop logic.

Comment: Thanks very much @RoQuOTriX, this looks like a great solution. I'll try it tomorrow, as my eyes are beginning to close by themselves. The following question may be impossible to answer of course, but do you have a sense of how much of a performance hit I will take by copying over the array rather than modifying it in place? This loop is part of a very demanding computational task and the number of columns may be very large.

Comment: Thanks very much again @RoQuOTriX, the solution works nicely in isolation, but unfortunately gives a segmentation fault when I slot it into my larger program. Something I'll have to ferret out myself.

Comment: Actually @RoQuOTriX, your code does not work in isolation if there are 2 or more separated columns that fulfill the criteria. `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` occurs. I think it is the same problem as before. The array `fog2` changes as its columns are removed, causing problems with the iteration of the (outer) loop (eg overrun of the array by the iterator).

Answer (score 1):

This solution, inspired by @RoQuOTriX, iterates over the original 2D `std::vector` array and selectively copies desired columns to a new array (instead of erasing undesired columns in the new array). The strategy solves the problem of iterating over a changing array.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


template <typename T>
inline void printArray (const std::vector< std::vector< T > >& key_array) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < key_array.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < key_array[i].size(); j++) {
            std::cout << key_array[i][j] << "\t";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    std::vector< std::vector <int> > fog {{1,2,1,2,2,1},{2,1,2,1,1,2},{3,3,3,3,3,3}};
    
    printArray(fog);
    
    std::vector< std::vector < double > > fog2(fog.size());

    for (int i = 0; i < fog[0].size(); ++i) {
                for (int j = 0; j < fog.size(); ++j) {
                    if (fog[0][i] < fog[1][i]) {
                        fog2.at(j).push_back(fog[j][i]);
                                }
                            }
                        }
    
    printArray(fog2);      
}
```

fog is:

```
1       2       1       2       2       1                                                                                      
2       1       2       1       1       2                                                                                      
3       3       3       3       3       3
```

and, as desired, fog2 is:

```
1       1       1                                                                                                              
2       2       2                                                                                                              
3       3       3
```

This approach removes all columns where `row 0 > row 1`, whether separated or contiguous, without causing a segmentation fault.

However, this approach is quite "heavy", requiring a deep copy. If anyone has a more efficient solution, I would love to hear it!

Comment: To try and take advantage of a shallow copy to speed up the code, I changed `fog2.at(j).push_back(fog[j][i])` to `fog2.at(j).push_back(std::move(fog[j][i]))`. The attempt was unsuccessful. The shallow copy worked, but was ~10% slower than the original deep copy.